my computer is getting slower than before, and I am still using outdated Ubuntu 16.04 version. would it becomes faster if I update it to 18.04?
with Ubuntu 16.04 many software are unable to update and always crash. Is this reasonable expectation to be faster with a newly version? And how can I do it safely?

Features of your computer? RAM - CPU - HD or SSD

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 have reached the end of life. That means they are not supported and are off topic here. You should upgrade to a currently supported version. Without knowing anything about your computer we can only provide opinions. Questions seeking opinions are off topic here.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately, there is no way to realistically answer this question. “Slow” is a subjective term that can mean very different things to different people. 18.04 is also out of support, but one one option would be to make a Live USB with 22.04 or 24.04 and try it out. If it seems responsive enough, consider installing the newer version. Upgrading would not be recommended, though. Make proper backups and perform a clean install.

Definitely don’t stick with a nearly 10-year-old release. I’d try a live session as others suggest and install if that works (22.04 or 24.04). If it is too sluggish, there are lighter weight options (eg lubuntu).

You can sign up for 16.04 Extended Security support for a couple more years here: https://ubuntu.com/security/esm. Note the latest Firefox you can install direct from Mozilla (.deb) format and Google Chromium you can install as a snap if Google Chrome is outdated. To answer your question the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Unity desktop (even with coimpiz) is probably just as fast, if not faster than Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. However, I'm not aware of anyone wanting to benchmark compare the two.

Some newer releases can be faster on some hardware, as software changes over time...  However toolkits & libraries also change; and some processors (esp. older) will execute newer code slower where as new CPUs will execute the newer code faster than the older versions... ie. there is a lot more involved than just the release... CPUs vary over time, and coding one way will benefit one model CPU, but others will be faster when coded others so your question is unanswerable as without specifics required.

My advise is to install Ubuntu Pro which provides 10 years of support. I just installed a dual-boot with 18.04.6 and 20.04.6. After you attach your computer and install all updates, you can upgrade to 18.04.
18.04 is great because its lightweight and does NOT have Tracker-Miner. Tracker-Miner is a CPU sucking nightmare. Look it up.
With 18.04 you will have support until 2030.
20.04 is similar to 18.04 but 22.04 is a different beast altogether.
Here is the link to Ubuntu Pro-- https://ubuntu.com/pro  --. It's free for personal use and you can attach 5 computers total. There is a fee for businesses.
Here is the release cycle and support schedule for Ubuntu releases:
https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle     .
BTW - I always recommend that people use Synaptic Package Manager to manage software and install updates. It's a "must-have" app.
here's the terminal command to install: sudo apt-get install synaptic   ......
Hope this helps.
